# Chef passing revision variable to deploy resource

Tags: ruby, git, deployment, chef-infra

I'm trying to pass the git branch that I want to deploy to the Chef deploy resource but it isn't working, I'm guessing it's because the resources are compiled separately and then just executed? But I might be wrong as my understanding of Ruby is limited.

So I'm trying to do this:

```
ruby_block 'revision' do
  block do
    # Some code determines the branch to be deployed
    branch = 'master'

    node.run_state['branch'] = branch

  end
end

deploy "#{node['path']['web']}" do
  action :deploy
  repository "#{node['git']['repository']}"
  revision "#{node.run_state['branch']}"
end
```

However the deploy resource doesn't get passed that variable.

Is this the correct way to go about this? Is there a better or other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment chef compiles your **deploy** resource **ruby_block** resource is not run yet, so node.run_state['branch'] is not set. You have to move your **deploy** resource into **ruby_block** and define it dynamically.

```
ruby_block 'revision' do
  block do
    # Some code determines the branch to be deployed
    branch = 'master'

    node.run_state['branch'] = branch

    depl = Chef::Resource::Deploy.new node['path']['web'], run_context
    depl.repository node['git']['repository']
    depl.revision node.run_state['branch']
    depl.run_action :deploy
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `run_context` coming from?

Comment: `run_context` is Recipe attribute. It's available in any recipe. https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/recipe.rb

Comment: It looks akin to a binding for a Chef run. Is that a fair analogy?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you.