# directory resource does not create directory

Tags: resources, vagrant, chef-infra, recipe

I have a Vagrantfile that provisions a VM by running a chef recipe. The first resource in the chef recipe is:

```
directory "/downloads" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end

# check that it worked:
raise "/downloads doesn't exist!" unless File.exists? "/downloads"
```

When I run this at work, it works fine.

When I run it at home, it fails, the exception is raised when I check to see if `/downloads` exists.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I would expect it to behave identically, since the underlying Vagrant box is the same both at work and at home. I am a chef newb so perhaps there is something I am not understanding about the order in which the resources are run within my recipe? I would expect them to run in sequential order...

I also tried putting a `notifies` call inside the `directory` block, where I call another `execute` block `:immediately`. That works, but inside the second execute block I test to see whether `/downloads` has been created and it hasn't.

Clearly I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef has two phases of execution: a compile phase and a converge phase.

In the compile phase, any resource declarations you write (like `directory`) are compiled but not executed. Any bare Ruby code you write is also executed at this time. In the converge phase, any compiled resources are then converged in a test-and-set operation.

I'm going to assume that at work, you already have a `/downloads` directory pre-existing, so the resource is a no-op during converge, and the raise doesn't happen during compile.

If you want arbitrary Ruby code to execute at converge time, put it in a `ruby_block` resource.

Comment: Thanks. How do I pass a variable between one resource declaration and another? Say I need to write ruby code (a ruby_block) to query some online resource which will tell me the name of a directory to create (in a directory block). Looks like I can say node.default['some_key'] = 'value' but that is sort of cumbersome.

Comment: You can stash things on node.run_state - it's an empty hash for that purpose, to pass things around the run, and which gets thrown away at the end.

Comment: Doesn't work. See minimal example: https://gist.github.com/dtenenba/87097fe75f72a1222f3e 
Results in "==> default: [2014-06-12T05:31:24+00:00] ERROR: nil is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.
==> default: [2014-06-12T05:31:24+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)"

Comment: I guess this is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019925/chef-passing-revision-variable-to-deploy-resource